# Word for including a fact into something that you do?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a verb in the following context which expresses that you

- take notice of something **and** include that into **the result** of your action.

Scenario:
You create a test for a software and you detect a behavior which is in some way unusual. You find out what the reason for this behavior is and you decide for yourself that this must be wrong. But because it is not part of your job to decide whether or not, you ignore it and you create the test in the way assuming that the behavior were correct.

> I ??? this <sub>(*imho incorrect*)</sub> behavior in my test.

All words that I find means either that you decide something to do or that you remember something:

- take something into account
- to bear/keep something in mind
- to consider
- to factor

But I don't want to express neither that you remember the *mistake* while creating the test nor that you *decided to ignore the mistake*.

The verb *to include* is the only one I can think of that works in the context, but have a bit different expression then the one I want to give. *To include* is in my understanding more like *just to insert*.

---

**Edit** for clarification: there is something that you know (you take notice of it) and you have a particular opinion about it ("it is wrong") but because you can't change it, you include that (wrong) behavior and handle it as if it were correct.

Comment: Tests should follow the specification, so this scenario shouldn't occur. The outcome is either what is specified, or it is not. If it isn't, it's a fail (and in that case, if you ignore it, *ignore* is exactly the word to use).

Comment: @AndrewLeach If you do black box testing you're right. In my case I don't have a specification in hand but the actual code.

Comment: I'm confused by your not wanting neither. Do you want both?

Comment: So you want to express both that you will remember the mistake and that you will decide to ignore it?

Comment: Per @Andrew's comment, it doesn't really make much sense to call your process a *"test"*, since apparently you don't actually know what the software should do anyway. Perhaps you should say you've created an *"example scenario"* to help someone else decide whether performance is as required.

Comment: @MattЭллен Ah, you mean the *But I don't want to express ...*-phrase? That's correct. The question is not about remember that there is a mistake (*I saw the mistake weeks ago and I remember*) and the question is also not about to decide to ignore the mistake (*OK, there is a mistake but I don't care). The question is about: (*There is something and I recognize it and included it somehow in my action, although I prefer not to do*). Another example (football): I noticed that you don't like to play as wing back so you play as middle back, although I think you were better at the wing.

Comment: @MattЭллен I added that part, because the words I listed expresses either memorization or decision. And they don't fit because of the reason that that's not what I want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good single word to express all that you are trying to express and fit in the sentence "I __ this behavior in my test."  I would have to say the closest for that particular case is *accepted* (as already suggested by jimreed).  It doesn't, by itself, indicate that you feel the behavior is wrong; it is a very neutral and factual statement of the situation.

If you want (and feel safe) to openly express that you feel the accepted behavior is wrong, just say so:  "I accepted this incorrect behavior in my test."

Since your question seems to be searching for a word that captures a certain feeling, even more so than it seems to be searching for a word to fit the sentence (because otherwise I can't make sense of the edit or the football comment), I'd like to offer a couple more:  *concede* and *acquiesce*.

*Concede* has a strong connotation of reluctance or unwillingness, but still expresses acceptance.  We often say that the loser "concedes defeat" to the winner.  Or you'll "concede a point" in an argument, even though you still feel you're correct, but it's not worth the time and effort for further discussion.

*Acquiesce* means to comply passively.  This word doesn't carry as much feeling of resistance as *concede*, but it also isn't very positive.  If your spouse wants to go to the theater but you would rather go to the football game, you may decide to acquiesce to her wishes, especially if she graciously watched football with you last weekend.

Comment: Since I believe that there isn't a word expressing what I'm looking for, this is the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *incorporate* would work: I incorporated this incorrect behavior into my test.

From Merriam-Webster:

1. a: to unite or work into something already existent so as to form an indistinguishable whole b: to blend or combine thoroughly

Examples of INCORPORATE

*This design incorporates the best features of our earlier models.*

*a diet that incorporates many different fruits and vegetables*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to say, but any of the following could possibly fit the scenario you describe:

> I **verified** this behavior in my test.
>
> I **acknowledged** this behavior in my test.
>
> I **assumed** this behavior in my test.
>
> I **accepted** this behavior in my test.

The last one may fit best with your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the word [revised](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revise)

> In light of the unexpected behaviour we revised the unit test to allow
>   it.

Comment: It's actually not what I'm looking for but somehow, though, it sounds very well. I like it. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

> I ***neglected to account for*** this behaviour in my test.
>
> [**neglect:**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neglect) to leave undone or unattended to especially through carelessness

If the omission was on purpose then this turns into (as others have suggested)

> I ***disregarded*** or ***ignored*** this behavior in my test.

*And* if the consequences of this omission are disasterous then this could turn into *negligence*

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to speak of **taking this behavior into account** or **accounting for** it.